# NHibernate Search - Method 'Merge' not implemented

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, s#arp-architecture, nhibernate.search

I've added NHibernate.Search to my otherwise routine S#arp Architecture 2.0 / MVC3 / .Net 4 project, followed directions pieced together from various tutorials, and it compiles fine, but I get a runtime exception:

`Method 'Merge' in type 'NHibernate.Search.Impl.FullTextSessionImpl' from assembly 'NHibernate.Search, Version=2.0.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.`

This happens when I try to run `var fullTextSession = Search.CreateFullTextSession(this.Session);` in a class which inherits `SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateRepository<T>` or `IFullTextSession session = Search.CreateFullTextSession(this.Session);` in a class based on `NHibernateQuery` (same namespace).

I have a reference to `NHibernate.Search` in my project (version 2.0.2.400 added via nuget) and it is set "Copy Local." I have tried using uninstall-package followed by install-package, but it offered no change.

Comment: I pulled NH Search from source, recompiled, and linked my project against that DLL. The exception still happens. I also tried removing NH from my projects and pulling that down from nuget (3.2.0.4000) and it still throws this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official NHibernate.Search repository has not been updated for a long time.
You may check [this repository on github](https://github.com/shosca/NHibernate.Search), it builds against NHibernate 3.2 and a recent version of Lucene.

Comment: Yes, I should have returned here to say I did that. I checked out a different fork (https://github.com/martinernst/NHibernate.Search/tree/v3.2) that was at least better, although I had to update it to use nuget packages. I'll check out that fork you linked there too, see if it works any better.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at http://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.Search/src/NHibernate.Search/NHibernate.Search.csproj?revision=1613&view=markup

It seems that NHibernate.Search is not built with latest NH, only thing I can suggest is to download/update and build yourself

Comment: Hm, OK, I'll pull latest NH into the NH Search source and see if that works.

Comment: `FullTextSessionImpl` is missing implementations of (new?) methods from `ISession` so I'll have to try downgrading my NH to 3.1

Comment: The last version of NH that NH Search will compile against seems to be 3.2.0.1002 ... the version of S#Arp I'm running seems to be compiled against 3.2.0.4000 so looks like I have to back that out too. I'll see if the version history on S#arp mentions when they upgraded NH... although maybe you know off-hand?

Comment: With a lot of work, I was able to downgrade my S#Arp, Fluent, and NHibernate versions to 2.0.0.3 rc, 1.2.0.712, 3.2.0.1002 respectively, and now everything works. Hopefully someone who understands the code better can update NHSearch in the near future to implement the missing methods, or I'll just implement them with `throw new NotImplementedException()` and not call them :D

Comment: @Carl Bussema do you mean you modifed the code to implement the interface by throwing exceptions?

Comment: For now I haven't done that, I just downgraded all my code to earlier versions that were compatible (see above for version numbers). But I have no reason to think that you couldn't just do what I suggest...